# Smoking whole beef blade steak

Tags: smoking

I want to smoke/slow cook whole blade. These are big pieces of meat, average 7kgs a piece. Dry rub, then how long at what temp and what internal temp should it get to? What sort of time frame, and should it be foil wrapped at some point ?

Answer (score 1):

This cut can be smoked similarly to a chuck roast or pot roast, which might help you search for recipes on your own.

As a baseline, you could try smoking it uncovered until it's around 150-170F, then foil wrap it and bring it up to 200F. This, along with letting it rest after you take it out, will ensure it doesn't dry out. This will take around 4-6 hours minimum.